# Save each iteration in a new line

Tags: loops, for-loop, beautifulsoup, save, iteration

friends! I have the following code:

```
   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  # 1 - Importar a página (html):

  início_url = 'https://www.conjugacao.com.br'
  final_url = ["/verbo-ir","/verbo-ser"]
  
  # 2 - Requisição:

  nome_verbos = []

  for final_url in final_url:

  url = início_url + final_url
  página = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(página.text, 'lxml')

  for verbos_nomes in soup.find_all('h1', class_='nmt'):
      nome_verbos.append(verbos_nomes.text)

  for items in soup.find_all('span', class_='f irregular'):
      nome_verbos.append(items.text)

  for items in soup.find_all('span', class_='f'):
      nome_verbos.append(items.text)
   
  # 3 Salvar resultados:

  with open('verbos.txt', 'w') as f:
      for line in nome_verbos:
          f.write(line.upper())
          f.write(',')
```

The output of this code is as follows:

```
   output:  VERBO IR,VOU,VAIS,VAI,VAMOS,IDES,VÃO, VERBO SER,SOU,ÉS,É,SOMOS,SOIS,SÃO
```

The only thing I need is to find out how to save this result like this:

```
   expected_output: 

   VERBO IR -> VOU, VAIS,VAI,VAMOS,IDES,VÃO
   VERBO SER -> SOU,ÉS,É,SOMOS,SOIS,SÃO
```

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

patterns = [
    'ir',
    'ser'
]


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for pat in patterns:
            r = req.get(url.format(pat))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
            name = soup.select_one('.nmt').text
            goal = [x.text for x in soup.select('.f, .irregular')]
            print(f"{name} --> {', '.join(goal)}")


main('https://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-{}')
```

Output:

```
Verbo Ir --> vou, vais, vai, vamos, ides, vão, fui, foste, foi, fomos, fostes, foram, fora, foras, fora, fôramos, fôreis, foram, fosse, fosses, fosse, fôssemos, fôsseis, fossem, vá, vás, vá, vamos, vades, vão, for, fores, for, formos, fordes, forem, vai, vá, vamos, ide, vão, vás, vá, vamos, vades, vão
Verbo Ser --> sou, és, é, somos, sois, são, era, eras, era, éramos, éreis, eram, fui, foste, foi, fomos, fostes, foram, fora, foras, fora, fôramos, fôreis, foram, fosse, fosses, fosse, fôssemos, fôsseis, fossem, seja, sejas, seja, sejamos, sejais, sejam, for, fores, for, formos, fordes, forem, sê, seja, sejamos, sede, sejam, sejas, seja, sejamos, sejais, sejam
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ahmded!!! I've added another goal variable, because there is anoter tag ('f') which is part of the verb as well. Thank you again!!!

Comment: @CygnusX-1 you don't need to assign class name `.f` individually! `.f.irregular` will find both classes

Comment: @Ahmed, .f and .f.irregular are two different tags: .f is for the regular parts of the verb, whereas .f.irregular are for the irregular parts of the verb. When I ran your script, it found only the irregular parts, but when I added another variable with that .f tag (goal + goal1), all parts of the verbs were scraped!! Thank you again, very kind of you to help me!!

Comment: @CygnusX-1 My bad, it was typo. try within `'.f, .irregular'`, also don't judge with names. it's `classes` not a `tags`

Comment: Indeed, @Ahmed, these are classes, not tags. And of course your answer helped me a lot!! I am very thankfull to you!!! See you, friend!! Hugs from Brazil!